# Magento 2 - shipping after clicking next Checkout shows empty

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-gateway

Console ::[image]

```
    Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.paypal.com/xoplatform/logger/api/logger. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active jquery-migrate.js:21:2
Object { disabled: false, create: null, url: "http://www.test.mydomain.com/" }
searchsuggestion.js:19:17
Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.[Learn More]
checkout
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://sg12.zopim.com/s/W/ws/2eT-e3okp++pm1XF/c/1543654229898. v2.zopim.com:39224:8
Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.[Learn More]
checkout
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated jquery-migrate.js:41:4
console.trace() jquery-migrate.js:43:5
migrateWarn
http://www.test.mydomain.com/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_AU/jquery/jquery-migrate.js:43:5
get
http://www.test.mydomain.com/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_AU/jquery/jquery-migrate.js:58:6
f<
http://www.test.mydomain.com/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_AU/jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9:677
<anonymous>
http://www.test.mydomain.com/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_AU/jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9:389
<anonymous>
http://www.test.mydomain.com/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_AU/jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9:2
Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.[Learn More]
checkout
Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead. script.js:60:8
Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element. knockout.js:2908:23
```

When click next after shipping

the checkout page shows empty

any payment gateway problem ????

Comment: Enable, disable payment gateway one by one you might know the which payment gateway having an issue

Comment: how to enable and disable module